# How to write Lua commands in Neovim with mod keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift etc)

Tags: lua, neovim

If I want to move cursor down with Lua in Neovim I can use the command

```lua
:lua vim.cmd('normal j')
```

'Ctrl-E' combination in Vim/Neovim scrolls the window one line down. How do I use it with Lua?
For example this approach does not work:

```lua
:lua vim.cmd('normal <C-e>')
```

How to provide modifier key sequences (Alt-, Ctrl-, Shift-) for Lua commands in Neovim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the keycode using `vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes()`. See [the section on that function in nanotee's Nvim Lua Guide](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#vimapinvim_replace_termcodes) and in the [Neovim API docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_replace_termcodes()).

```lua
:lua vim.cmd(vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes('normal <C-e>'))
```

In my config I go with nanotee's advice and define a helper function to avoid spelling out that insanely long function name.

```lua
local function t(str)
    return vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes(str, true, true, true)
end
```

That shortens your example to

```lua
vim.cmd(t('normal <C-e>'))
```

if used in a scope where `t()` is defined.

Comment: If your ```_G``` has no metatable than make ```_G``` to a NeoVIM Object with: ```setmetatable(_G, {__index = vim.api}) -- Makes vim.api Content global``` after that you can do: ```:lua nvim_input('iHello World with ' .. _VERSION .. '\nFrom: ' .. jit.version .. '\nOn: nvim ' .. (vim.version().minor) .. '<Esc>')``` - Logic: If ```nvim_input``` not present in ```_G``` than ```__index``` will be triggered and command will be found there

Comment: This answer helped me a lot because the `vim.cmd` did not worked for me in any way until I used the `t(str)` function, eve when using `vim.cmd.normal(t('...'))`. Thanks a lot!